# Find by some array items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a given array `A = [5, 15, 25, 35]`.

I have a collection C. All its documents have the field 'numbers', which is an array of numbers, with variable lengths.

I want to match all documents which have, as elements of 'numbers', at least 2 of the 4 elements of A. How should I efficiently proceed?

It would be nice to use find and not need aggregate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `aggregation` it's easy. You need to use `$size` with `$setIntersection` and then match all the documents with element at least 2 numbers in the intersected array:

```
db.C.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            numbers: 1,
            intersectedNumbers: {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: ['$numbers', [5,15,25,35]]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'intersectedNumbers': {
                $gte: 2
            }
        }
    }
])
```

With `find` it's more problematic since you need two stages as in the `aggregation` above, and it's not possible with `find`.
But what you can do, if the `A` array is dynamic, is to create a function that will return all possibiltes of "at least 2" elements, and then use `$or` and `$all` to use `find`:

```
db.C.find({
    $or: [
        {numbers: {$all: [5,15]}},
        {numbers: {$all: [5,25]}},
        {numbers: {$all: [5,35]}},
        {numbers: {$all: [15,25]}},
        {numbers: {$all: [15,35]}},
        {numbers: {$all: [25,35]}}
    ]
})
```